# Question on Cauchy filters

Tags: general-topology, filters, uniform-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{V})$ is a uniform space and $\xi$ is a Cauchy filter on $(X,\mathcal{V})$.

> $o(\xi)$ is the family of all open subsets of $X$ containing at least one element of $\xi$.

what does "containing at least one element of $\xi$" mean? that is, for every elements $V$ of $o(\xi)$ there exist at least one $A\in\xi$ such that $A\subset V$; or somthing else?
Is $o(\xi)$ a Cauchy filter on $(X,\mathcal{V})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$U\in o(\xi)$ iff $U\subseteq X$ is open in the topology induced by $\mathcal V$ and there exists some $A\in \xi $ such that $A\subseteq U$. In general, $o(\xi)$ will not be a filter since there is no reason for it to have the property that if $U\subseteq V$ and $U\in o(\xi)$, then $V\in o(\xi)$ (as $V$ may easily fail to be open).

Comment: $o(\xi)$ is however, a filter-base for the _minimal Cauchy filter_ contained in $\xi$. Just thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Is it true that A Cauchy filter $\mathscr{A}$ is called Minimal cauchy filter if it contains no proper subfamily which is a Cauchy filter?

Comment: @TXC Yes. The family of Cauchy filters is partially ordered by inclusion, and "minimal" refers to that partial order. The important - and perhaps surprising - fact is that each Cauchy filter contains a unique minimal Cauchy filter, thus the completion of a uniform space $X$ can without factoring out an equivalence relation be constructed as the space of minimal Cauchy filters on $X$ (defining the uniform structure, and verifying everything is a bit cumbersome, though).